# Separate areas algorithm

Tags: algorithm, geometry

We are given an N x M rectangular area with K lines in it. Every line has (x0,y0) - (x1,y1), beginning and end coordinates. Are there some well known  algorithms or resources to learn that can help me to write a program to find how many separate areas those lines form in the rectangular area?

If this is the original rectangular area : http://prntscr.com/6p9m2c
Then there are 4 separate areas: http://prntscr.com/6p9mo5

Comment: Can you say anything about the lines and how they relate to the area?  For example, are they line segments or effectively infinitely long?

Comment: They are line segments with endpoints x0,y0 - x1, y1, And they are inside the borders of the area. For example this rectangle has 6 independent areas. http://www.oldschool.com.sg/modpub/24734354047a5d1609a64b

Comment: Are x0,y0 and x1,y1 always on the border of the area?

Comment: Sorry for the previous answer, but no they are not always on the border of the area, they can be from 1 to border.length length

Comment: Are all the lines axis aligned? Are you dealing with real geometry, or character-based geometry like your diagram suggests?

Answer (score 1):

All segments with intersections form [planar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph). You have to count thoroughly vertices and edges of this graph, then apply [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula)

```
 F = E - V + 2
```

where
V is vertice count - number of intersections (and corners and free segment ends)
E is edge count - number of segments, formed **after** intersections
F is number of facets.
Your needed region count is

```
R = F - 1
```

because F takes into account outer facet.

For your example - there are 16 vertices, 10 horizontal edges and 9 vertical, so

```
R = 10 + 9 - 16 + 2 - 1 = 4
```

Note that you can either count vertices with degree 1,2 (corners and free ends) or ignore them together with one neighbour segment (simplify graph) - this doesn't influence to result.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that the NxM grid is a graph where each '.' is a vertex, and two vertex is connected by an edge if they are side by side (above, below, on the side). Now each separate area corresponds to a connected component of the graph, and you can count the number of connected components in O(N*M) using BFS or DFS algorithms.